# why c is not reading the value of i in the strncpy function

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that deletes the last letter after each new line. I don't know why it isn't working but in case I set the value of i in the `strncpy` function with any number it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  char s[]="ordinateur";
  char a[strlen(s)+1];
  for (i=0;i<=strlen(s);i++)
  {
    strncpy(a,s,(10-i));
    printf("%s\n",a);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `strncpy` does not NUL terminate the string when you only copy a part of the source string. So you need to handle that yourself.

One way is to add this

```
memset(a, 0, strlen(s)+1);
```

just **before** the `strncpy`

Another way is to add this

```
a[10-i] = '\0';
```

just **after** the `strncpy`

That said, please notice that you don't need `strncpy` inside the loop to delete the last letter. You can simply do:

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  char s[]="ordinateur";
  for (i=strlen(s); i>0 ; i--)
  {
    printf("%s\n",s);
    s[i-1] = '\0';     // Remove last char
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles and works (your sample wouldn't compile on my IDE because strlen doesn't return a constant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char s[] = "ordinateur";
    char a[11 + 1];
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(s); i++)
    {
        strncpy_s(a, s, (10 - i));
        printf("%s\n", a);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which AFAIK is discouraged. Instead you should use memory allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  size_t i;
  char s[] = "ordinateur";
  char *a = calloc(strlen(s) + 1);

  for (i = 0; i<= strlen(s); i++) {
    strncpy(a,s, 10 - i);
    printf("%s\n",a);
  }

  free(a);

  return 0;
}
```